# Finding 2 different functions to satisfy the same requirement

Tags: functions

I got $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}: x \rightarrow x^2$

Now I have to find two different functions $g1: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}$ and $g2: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}$ So that $g1 \circ f  = g2 \circ f = Id(\mathbb{N})$, whereas $Id(\mathbb{N})$ is the identity on $\mathbb{N}$

I would have said that $g1: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}: x \rightarrow \sqrt(x)$. But how do I find a second one which is not identical?

Comment: Your function $g_1$ does not map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, since, for example, $\sqrt{2}$ is not a natural number.  Perhaps this gives you a hint as to what you need to do.

Comment: Well couldnt I say then, that simply each x^2 gets mapped to x?

Comment: @M3xr not each x will map to $\mathbb{N}$. Try 15 for example.

Comment: @M3xr As you've seen in the comments, that's right.  You need every square to go to its (non-negative) square root, but you can do whatever you want with the non-square numbers, as they are never mapped to by $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\;g_1(x) = \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor\;$ and $\;g_2(x) = \lfloor \sqrt{x+1} \rfloor$.

---

[ EDIT ]  As pointed out in a comment, the $g_2$ formula above only works for $x \ge 1$. If $\mathbb{N}$ is considered to include $0$ then $g_2(0)=0$ must be defined as a separate case.

[ EDIT #2 ]  Per @Shagnik's comment, it is also possible to choose a (different) nicer $g_2(x)=\lceil \sqrt{x}\; \rceil$ which works for $x \ge 0$ without requiring a special case definition for $0$.

Comment: I see, this makes sense!

Comment: Does not work for $x=0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut In the school where $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ one would define $g_2(0)=0$ as a separate case.

Comment: That's right. Just an uninteresting corner case, nevertheless a part of the answer. And, yes, I belong to that school :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That's a fair point. I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: An alternative would be to take $g_2(x) = \lceil \sqrt{x} \; \rceil$, and then one does not need to treat $x = 0$ as a special case.

Comment: @Shagnik Indeed, thanks. I edited that into my answer (with the proper attribution).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this for example:
$g_1(x)= \sqrt{x}$ if x is a square number, $g_1(x)=x$ otherwise
$g_2(x)= \sqrt{x}$ if x is a square number, $g_2(x)=1$ otherwise

Comment: So basically, that is just  a way to work around dealing with square roots of non-square numbers in order to have a function g that is correctly defined? Because as f(x) will always be a square number, it doesnt matter what g(x) is in the other cases as long as it is a natural number?

Comment: Yes you got it right (this was more or less your intuition on your initial comments).